# Can I export certificates from Credentials Storage

Tags: certificates

I have several certificates in the Credentials store that I would like to backup. Can they be extracted?

OnePlus 2 running OxygenOS 2.2.0 Android 5.1.1
Not Rooted.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: This device is not rooted.

Comment: Well, unless you want to modify them it should do without. Certs are stored in a specific directory (`/system/etc/security` for system certs, `/data/misc/keychain/certs-added` for user certs) one per file, so you could just copy them to your PC if you like. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22040887/2533433) for details.

Comment: /data does not appear to be accessible. Access denied using FX explorer. perhaps I will root the device and have another go.